# How to render sanitized text properly in webpage?

Tags: html, node.js, express, express-validator

I'm using expressjs' express-validator to sanitize/escape user input before storing it in my mongoDB.

If I try to store a URL in my mongodb after sanitizing it, it is store as

```
https:&#x2F;&#x2F;www.youtube.com&#x2F;watch?v=IEwEDTmqCEs
```

When I try to show it on the webpage, the browser does not replace the / automatically like it would with

Basically I want to escape users input to avoid XSS attack and DB injection but show the text properly when in HTML for as below

```
https://www.youtube.com&/watch?v=IEwEDTmqCEs
```

Are there any npm packages that would easily handle encoding and decoding on server side so that I don't have to use the hacky way of using textarea in HTML to decode text properly in a safe way

Answer (score 1):

I was just had to use <%- %> instead of the <%= %> tags. That worked for my case.